# Can we use one WordPress installation for multiple databases, domains and content directories

Tags: customization, multisite

I have seen some questions which look similar, but they all ended up with [multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). For maintainability, performance and security, I don't want to use multisite. So please bear with me.

This is what I'm thinking about:

```
.
|_____branch1 // for branch1.domain.com
|  |_____themes
|  |_____plugins
|
|_____branch2 // for branch2.domain.com
|  |_____themes
|  |_____plugins
|
|_____branch3 // for branch3.domain.com
|  |_____themes
|  |_____plugins
|
|_____index.php
|_____WordPress
|_____wp-config.php
```

As you can see, each domain has its own database and content directory but just one WordPress instance. Now, themes, plugins and databases become smaller and independent. Then, it would be much easier to maintain, scale...

But is it possible? If you have experienced the same problem before, please share your thoughts! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why was multisite eliminated as a possibility? Doing this will involve creating a fragile system that will be less maintainabable than multisite, have slower performance than multisite, and worse security than multisite. Some of the largest installs of WordPress are multisite installs, and it's all the same code that runs on a standard single site

Comment: I manage multiple WP multisites including one that has over 500 sub-sites.  Performance will be the same whether you use one multisite or 500 WP instances unless you have the 500 instances on separate VMs and databases. Maintainability sucks with multisite?  Try maintaining 500 number of single sites.

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm not sure if that largest installs using only one database as it is but I think [this](https://wordpress.tv/2015/05/31/taylor-mccaslin-multisite-network-dos-and-donts-experience-from-an-enterprise-solution/) and [this video](http://wordpress.tv/2014/05/13/sam-hotchkiss-large-multisite-networks-our-experiences-in-enterprise/) might bring us to a same page. We're mainly using WordPress for CRM and user privacy is very important.

Comment: @user42826 Currently, my company don't have that much sites. I also cannot convert current site to a multisite and benchmark it. And hardware and other things might different from you. So I just want to ask about an optimal installation architecture in my case. As far as I know, multisite works with subdomains but it cannot works for different domains.

Comment: Multisite works with different domains. We use a main domain, *.domain.com, and a few other domains, www.domain2.com and www.domain3.com. We use WP Domain mapping plugin to accomplish multidomains, but from what I hear WP core supports multidomain mapping now natively.

Comment: @user42826 Thank for your suggestion! I will do some research about that ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [@tom-j-nowell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) said in comment to OP, multisite can make this easier.

Performance and security are not really a problem for multisite (at least, not more than they are for regular installations), but I do agree that multisite can sometimes be a problem, because a lot of plugins (either custom or 3rd party) may not work properly on multisite, or maybe because you want to keep users of different websites completely separated.

That said what you want to achieve is not that hard.

What you need to change between installation is:

- plugins folder
- themes folder
- database settings

Those configuration can be done using [constants in `wp-config.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) your only problem is how to switch them based on URL.

The server variable `'SERVER_NAME'` should work for you, at least if your webserver is configured properly.

For example you can create a folder named `/conf` at the same level of `wp-config.php` file and `/WordPress` folder.

In that folder you can add some files:

- `branch1.domain.com.conf`
- `branch2.domain.com.conf`
- `branch3.domain.com.conf`

inside each of them you can do something like

```
$branch = 'branch1';
$base_dir = dirname( __DIR__) . "/{$branch}";

defined( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR' ) or define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $base_dir );

// be sure WP understand URLs correctly
defined( 'DB_HOME' ) or define( 'DB_HOME', "{$branch}.example.com" );
defined('WP_SITEURL') or define('WP_SITEURL', "{$branch}.example.com/WordPress");

// adjust DB settings  as needed
defined( 'DB_NAME' ) or define( 'DB_NAME', $branch );
defined( 'DB_USER' ) or define( 'DB_USER', $branch );
defined( 'DB_PASSWORD' ) or define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '********' );

unset( $base_dir, $branch );
```

This will change on each configuration file according to the "branch".

After that, in your unique `wp-config.php` you can so something like:

```
$defaults_conf = [
  'WP_CONTENT_DIR' => __DIR__ . '/branch1',
  'DB_HOST'        => 'localhost',
  'DB_NAME'        => 'branch1',
  'DB_USER'        => 'branch1',
  'DB_PASSWORD'    => '********',
];

$host = getenv('WORDPRESS_HOST') ?: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if ($host && file_exists(__DIR__."/conf/{$host}.conf")) {
  require __DIR__."/conf/{$host}.conf";
}

array_walk($defaults_conf, function($value, $name) {
   defined($name) or define($name, $value);
});

unset($defaults_conf, $host);
```

What happen above is that based on the server name you load a different configuration file (if found) and if the configuration file does not define any of the default configuration (or if the file is not found) configuration are set per default.

Nice thing is that to add a new branch, you just need to create the branch folder and provide a `.conf` named after the new branch domain, and you are done, there's nothing to change on WP side.

The line:

```
 $host = getenv('WORDPRESS_HOST') ?: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

is where I get the domain name. As first option I'm using an environment variable, because there're chances `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will not work on a command line context, such us when using WP CLI. In those situations you can set an environment variable to force WP to use settings from a specific branch.

Note that in branch-specific config files I'm changing the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and that will automatically set plugins and themes folder to the related `/plugins` and `/themes` branch subfolders.

A possible issue here is if you want to share the `/uploads` folder (where files get uploaded).

By default that folder is a subfolder of content dir, so using workflow above it will be an `/uploads` subfolder of each branch root folder.

If that is not a problem for you, than just go with it, otherwise the easiest solution would be to make `/uploads` in each branch folder a symlink to the *real* uploads folder you want to share.

Comment: Thank you! I really like your idea even though [`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is not reliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name#answer-2297446). `/uploads` dir isn't problem. I have also tested with WP CLI, if we pass in `--url` parameter for each site, it works normally :)

Comment: @Dan I said in the answer: _"The server variable 'SERVER_NAME' should work for you, at least if your webserver is configured properly."_ It means that you need to configure your server properly :) In fact, as long as you setup `server_name` in nginx or `ServerName` in Apache or whatever fits your web server, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will just works. Even if WP CLI may works using `--url` parameter, other command line tools may have issues if you dont use the environment variable. WP CLI "mocks" the URL of the request in a CLI context, other commands probably won't do it.

Comment: Of course, I will make sure that `SERVER_NAME` is configured properly. About env vars, I have used [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to fix it. Currently, everything seem to work great :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a symlinking and a bit of planning.  I did some scouring on the net for the same thing.  Finally, put together all the stuff and got it working.

I have been running a few websites, they all share the same theme and plugin folder. Same folders work for multisite and single sites.  But you have to be careful about certain plugins which can be Multi/Single site only and be quirky.

I have made a directory like master-tnp/themes and master-tnp/plugins.  Then symlink to your wordpress directory using ln -s command.

Pitfalls are in server configurations as well.  Ensure follow symlinks directive is set to allow.

If you want to use a Single WordPress installation, I have put together a detailed guide as to how I did it at https://vaish.co/multiple-sites-single-wordpress-directory

Comment: Your link is not working anymore but I found an archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170108180021/https://vaish.co/multiple-sites-single-wordpress-directory/
Didn't symlinks cause problems with the `__FILE__` constant like mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794063/leaving-wordpress-core-files-untouched-shared-between-multiple-blog-installation?